# Tcpdf on Laravel 3 controller

Tags: laravel, tcpdf, laravel-3

Good morning. I'm trying to generate a Pdf with  Tcpdf library and bundle. I tested the basic usage of the library on a controller like this:

```
public function get_reporte_grupos(){           
    $pdf = new Tcpdf();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('times','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
}
```

And my output is like the de binary of the pdf file:

> %PDF-1.7 % 8 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified
>   (D:20130725101953-04'30') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000
>   0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000
>   0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 9 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 7 0 R ] /PZ
>   1 >> endobj 9 0 obj <> stream xSN0+[{qW(-ꩀ%^H(Uh8R().. and so on.

What I'm missing here? I don't wanna use html2pdf because the kind of files I'm generating is way too extense and I have to get control of the page break in order to do some maths. So what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I was gonna to delete the question, but I'll answer if someone comes with the same problem. On the controller replace

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

with

```
return Response::make($pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I'), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
```

And  you'll get your pdf file.

Comment: Thank Cheluis,you saved my day, I thought it was something of laravel with TCPDF, I thought I was the last alternative reescribiri the index.php because it was a problem with the engine blade templates.

Comment: @Cheluis Hi! I have the same problem, what is `Response::make`? Thanks.